# MySQL - Comparing Two Negative Time Values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-timestamp

I have the following conditional statement in my SQL query:

```
WHERE TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", VARIABLE) >= "00:05:00"
```

The above works as expected.  If the value returned from **TIMEDIFF()** is greater than 5 minutes, the record it represents will be returned.  If **TIMEDIFF()** returns `-02:00:00`, `-00:05:00`, or `00:04:00`, then the record would be excluded.  If it returns `00:06:00` or `01:02:00`, the corresponding record will be included in the query results.

I need to update the above conditional statement to:

```
WHERE TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", VARIABLE) >= "-00:05:00"
```

In the updated statement, only values greater than or equal to `-00:05:00` should be included in the results.  I noticed that this isn't the case.  Even records with corresponding larger negative values returned by **TIMEDIFF()** - ie. `-05:00:00`, `-02:00:00`, `-00:06:00` - are being returned with this new conditional statement.

It seems that MySQL has trouble comparing two negative time values against one another.

Is there any way to accurately write this comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `TIME_TO_SEC` to convert time format to integer second then compare your values

like below

```
where TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", VARIABLE))>=-300
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql can work with time in the range from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`.

First, you should make sure `TIMEDIFF()` returns correct time. For example, `TIMEDIFF()` can return an error with using `jdbc driver` in cases with negative time.
You can check it with the simple query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("02:55:00", "03:00:00")
```

if result is '-05:00:00' then a driver works correctly.

Secondly, you should cast your time value in time type manually, because MySQL can cast a negative time value to time type incorrectly.

```
WHERE TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", VARIABLE) >= TIME("-00:05:00")
```

For example:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", "3:00:00") >= "-00:05:00"; // return true
SELECT TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", "3:10:00") >= "-00:05:00"; // return true
```

This query always returns `true`, but if you cast '-00:05:00' to time type manually this queries will return the correct results

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", "3:00:00") >= TIME("-00:05:00"); // return true
SELECT TIMEDIFF("03:00:00", "3:10:00") >= TIME("-00:05:00"); // return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you could use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)), in order to do that, you need convert your hard coded value twice (if you cast it directly to `datetime`, it `TIMESTAMPDIFF` won't work properly), like this:

```
create table tbl (t time);
insert into tbl values ("00:06:00"), ("00:03:00"), ("-00:06:00"), ("-00:03:00");
-- here you can see how it works
select *,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, cast(cast("00:05:00" as time) as datetime), cast(t as datetime))
from tbl;
```

Mentioned function will return an integer, which will be easy to compare against :)